# How to make the bot leave a guild with a command in discord.py?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I want the bot leave a guild with a command . I tried this:

```
 @commands.command()
    @commands.check(user_is_me)
    async def leave(self,guild_id):
        await self.bot.get_guild(int(guild_id)).leave()
```

But this throws me the following error,

```
Ignoring exception in command leave:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Rohit\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 83, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\Users\Rohit\Desktop\discord bots\quotient\cogs\owner.py", line 47, in leave
    await self.bot.get_guild(int(guild_id)).leave()
TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'Context'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Rohit\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 892, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\Rohit\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 797, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Rohit\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 92, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'Context'
```

How do I solve it?

Comment: error shows you problem with `int()` so check what you try to convert in int()` - `print(guild_id)`, print( type(guild_id) )`. It is not string but some class `Context` . Maybe you used misleading name and you should use rather `def leave(self, context)` and then you can try to get `guild_id` from `context`

Comment: I check doc and normally you should have `def leave(context, guild_id)` but it seems your  use it in class and you have `self` (class instance) as first argument but you still need `context` (or `ctx`) as first argument after `self` - so you should have rather `def leave(self, context, guild_id)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you check documentation for [command](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/commands.html) you see example like

```
@commands.command()
def test(ctx, arg)
```

When you use it in class then you have `self` as first argument but you still need other arguments

```
@commands.command()
def test(self, ctx, arg)
```

In you code it will be

```
def leave(self, ctx, guild_id)
```

But you use `leave(self, guild_id)` so you get `context` in variable `guild_id` and later you try to use this `context` in `int()` and in error message you get information about `Context`

```
int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'Context'
```